# Combining select statements fetching data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm trying to combine two select statements, the first statement selects all users that a user is following and the second statement selects all notes of the user and all the other users they are following:

```php
$get_user = $user_data['username'];
$get_following = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM follows WHERE `follower` = '$get_user'");
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM  posts WHERE username = '$followe' OR username = '$get_user' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,5 ");
```

I tried using the following code but it only fetches a single entry when the user is following more than one person:

```php
$get_following = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM follows WHERE `follower` = '$get_user'");
$ffg =mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_following);
$ff = $ffg['follower'];
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM  posts WHERE username = '$ff' OR username = '$get_user' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,5 ");
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve data from multiple tables using php form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941495/how-to-retrieve-data-from-multiple-tables-using-php-form)

Comment: @ZacWebb it does not help,pls.

Comment: Your goal is not clear to me. You want to build a statement to select all followers *and* their posts?